# Login into Sharepoint Site from Web service

Tags: web-services, fast-for-sharepoint

Is this possible to login into the SharePoint site using the username and password from web service soap header?

Thanks
SR

Comment: Have a look at the first response in this question
http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/13002/windows-authentication-with-sharepoint-web-services-via-soap

Answer (score 1):

If your SharePoint site is using FBA, you can use [authentication.asmx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/websvcauthentication%28v=office.14%29.aspx) webservice to get the authentication cookie. If your site is using Windows, you can directly assign defaultcredentials of logged in user like :

proxy.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

Comment: Hi @Amit Kumawat thanks for your response. My site is using Windows Authentication. I have valid username and password in web service. So i need to pass that user to the sharepoint site like                                     /* using (SPSite site = new SPSite("url", usertoken)) */