# PasswordNotMatch error in authentication.asmx web service

Tags: web-services, authentication

I am trying to authenticate to SharePoint site using the authentication.asmx web service. The code is as below.

```
  public bool Authenticate()
  {
    String username = "......"; 
    String password = "......";
    Cookie _authCookie;
    CookieContainer _cookieContainer;


    AuthService.Authentication authentication = new AuthService.Authentication();
    authentication.Url = "<web_url>/_vti_bin/Authentication.asmx";
    authentication.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
    authentication.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
    authentication.PreAuthenticate = true;
    AuthService.LoginResult loginResult = authentication.Login(username, password);

    _authCookie = new Cookie();

    if (loginResult.ErrorCode == AuthService.LoginErrorCode.NoError)
    {
        CookieCollection cookies = authentication.CookieContainer.GetCookies(new Uri(authentication.Url));
        _authCookie = cookies[loginResult.CookieName];
        _cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        _cookieContainer.Add(_authCookie);
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
  }
```

But I am getting an error "PasswordNotMatch" in ErrorCode, even though the username and password I am entering is correct.

The **AuthService** is a Service Reference to the *authentication.asmx* web service

Did anybody solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

the question has been answered before, look at ashish answer as it implements your code. I think the area your going wrong is in the cookie part.

[Windows authentication with SharePoint Web Services via SOAP](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/13002/windows-authentication-with-sharepoint-web-services-via-soap)

the code is for list authentication but a slight alteration would give you site authentication. The principal is the same!

**EDIT**

```
AuthService.Authentication authentication = new AuthService.Authentication();
authentication.Url = "<web_url>/_vti_bin/Authentication.asmx";
authentication.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
authentication.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
authentication.PreAuthenticate = true;
AuthenticationSoap authenticationSoap = null;
authenticationSoap = authentication.getAuthenticationSoap();
AuthServiceLoginResult loginResult = authenticationSoap.Login(username, password);
```

try adding the authentication soap call aswell! should work for on-premise

a similar answer answered by me here [How to authenticate user in SharePoint online using javascript](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/79803/how-to-authenticate-user-in-sharepoint-online-using-javascript) it also explains on soap calls.

Comment: I've tried with the code given in the link. But still I am getting the error "PasswordNotMatch".

Comment: are you 100% sure the account name and password is correct?

Comment: This is a domain account. And I use the credentials to login to the server. I've tried the username with both email id and domain\\username format

Comment: what version of sharepoint are you using? onpremise or online? if its online than its not supported.

Comment: It is SharePoint 2013 on-premise

Comment: Tried with another server. Same issue "PasswordNotMatch". Why is it not supported in online/Office365?

Comment: Is it a server configuration issue? Maybe I missed it. Any idea?

Comment: i am getting also problem with authentication, if you have example to authenticate then please share with us

Comment: just updated my answer